# Where is FragmentActivity#onDetachFragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

Every time I attach a fragment to my activity, I want to register it to receive events from the activity. This is easy, because I can override [`FragmentActivity#onAttachFragment(Fragment)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#onAttachFragment%28android.support.v4.app.Fragment%29). When the fragment is removed from the activity, I want to unregister it from receiving events. I expected there to be a `onDetachFragment` event that I could use in a similar manner, but I'm not finding it.

Is there another way to accomplish what I'm trying to do? I'd like to keep the registering/unregistering in the activity, as opposed to moving it to a base fragment class (where I could just use `onAttach`/`onDetach`).

Comment: its better to use the onStart(), onStop() method from your fragment. Just cast getActivity() to your calling activity class.

Comment: @Anis It looks like that's the only way available. If you make your comment an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I'm sorry for the following rant, but I just want to add that today, July 2018, I'm casually facing a trivial problem that I would be able to solve with a single line, were onDetachFragment available. Instead, I need to write, test and debug several convoluted lines of boilerplate code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

its better to use the onStart(), onStop() method from your fragment. Just cast getActivity() to your calling activity class.

Comment: Can you please explain why that is better?

Comment: its better because at this stage the fragment is attached to its parent activity.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better design for parent to set the listeners on the fragment vs the fragment grabbing the listeners from the parent?

Comment: Or... cast it to the fragment's expected "listener" type (provided the attached Context/Activity passes the `instanceof` check) and your fragment doesn't have to know anything about your activity. Your fragment's onAttach/onDetach methods would be a great spot for this.